# criar um Pre (ETL) Extract, transform, load com console c#

Tags: c#

Estou com uma atividade e não sei por onde iniciar, tenho que criar um **Pre ETL** para consumir e transformar um `.txt` segue dados:

**Lista de Preço**

O arquivo de Lista de Preço chegará com o seguinte nome: `XBOL_QP_PL_OUT_20181010.txt`

**Pré ETL** deve recepcionar esse arquivo, e dividi-lo em dois:

**Cabeçalho:** `XBOL_QP_PL_OUT_H_20181010.txt`
**Item:** `XBOL_QP_PL_OUT_L_20181010.txt`

***Regra*** `XBOL_QP_PL_OUT_H_20181010.txt`:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Arquivo com separador PIPE (|);
- Primeira posição, caractere de 1, identificador “H” (Header);
- Manter o mesmo `timestamp` do arquivo original;

Arquivo deve ficar com a nomenclatura original.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Regra*** `XBOL_QP_PL_OUT_L_20181010.txt`:

- Arquivo com separador PIPE (|);
- Primeira posição, caractere de 1, identificador “L” (Lines);
- Manter o mesmo `timestamp` do arquivo original;

Arquivo deve ficar com a nomenclatura original.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a sua duvida, apesar que com esse arquivo eu já fiquei na duvida também porque o arquivo base é igual os outros arquivos mas, com cabeçalho diferente? o que é realmente pra fazer?

Comment: Uma pasta vai receber o arquivo TXT que vai ter os dados das linhas H e L nesse arquivo, preciso separar em 2 arquivos, um para linhas H e outro pra linhas L  e jogar em outra pasta, isso tudo em um console C#

Comment: E ai entendeu a solução?

Comment: Muito obrigado Virgilio vou testar agora ! te aviso assim que tiver OK

Comment: Funcionou muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente faz a leitura no arquivo principal (com a classe [StreamReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8))  e com o comando [Substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) da linha que é do tipo `string` faz uma comparação da primeira posição descobrindo se a linha é do arquivo H ou do arquivo L e adiciona nas respectivos arquivos e adiciona linha a linha nos arquivos referentes a cada arquivo novo a ser criado (com a classe [StreamWriter](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.8)), **exemplo**:

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"./base.txt");
System.IO.StreamWriter fileH = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"./baseH.txt");
System.IO.StreamWriter fileL = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"./baseL.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Substring(0, 1) == "H")
    {
        fileH.WriteLine(line);
    }
    else
    {
        fileL.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
fileH.Flush();
fileH.Dispose();
fileL.Flush();
fileL.Dispose();

file.Close();
file.Dispose();
```

<sub>***Ref.***</sub>

- [String.Substring Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8)
- [StreamReader Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8)
- [StreamWriter Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.8)

---

Um outra maneira com [System.Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-4.8) junto com [Substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8)

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"./base.txt");
IEnumerable<string> linesH = lines.Where(x => x.Substring(0, 1) == "H");
IEnumerable<string> linesL = lines.Where(x => x.Substring(0, 1) == "L");
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"./baseH.txt", linesH);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"./baseL.txt", linesL);
```

<sub>***Ref.***</sub>

- [System.Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-4.8)